# Using R: Get a users followers from a specific location

Tags: r, twitter

I started to learn R, but now I am stuck.

I want to analyse followers from a specific twitter account. The problem is that that profile has a lot of followers, so to get all followers would take much time. And I am just interested in the followers from Switzerland.

So I wonder if its possible to just load the data of followers who are coming from switzerland?

This is what I already have:

```
library("twitteR")
    consumer_key <- "my_key"
    consumer_secret <- "my_secret"
    access_token <- "my_token"
    access_secret <- "my_secret"
    options(httr_oauth_cache=T) #This will enable the use of a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions.
    setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,
                         consumer_secret,
                         access_token,
                         access_secret)
    [1] "Using direct authentication"

    trump <- getUser("RealDonaldTrump")
    follower <- trump$getFollowers(retryOnRateLimit=180)
```

So, the last line of code obviously would take hours, so I need a better solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what information you want about each follower? Do you want a count of how many followers list "Switzerland" as their home country? Or do you want more information about each user?

My understanding is that the API doesn't permit the filtering of followers' output on a field such as country. Thus, it seems to me, that one would need to collect all users' information, then filter, after the fact, on the country.

I collected the user ID numbers for all of Donald Trump's followers in June 2016 (when he had fewer than 10 million followers, I think). It took some time, but, with the use of the smappR package & smappR::getFriends function, it was easy to do. I'm sure that it will take longer now that he has many more followers, but the procedure with smappR::getFriends should work.

It will, however, require some additional time to download the user information for each user ID. I think that you'll need to make a distinct query to a twitter API to get the user information, as smappR::getFriends will give only the user IDs (and maybe the user names). You would then need to query an API with a function like smappR::getUsers to get their user information, including country of residence. I admit that my understanding of Twitter APIs is incomplete, but I hope that this response helps.